# Threading's is_alive method not returning accurate state

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I want to setup a monitor using a thread reporting updates to a set of registered listeners. I'm using threading.Thread. Thread should be started with the registration of the first listener, second and proceeding listener just being added to the list of listeners.
I'm facing the situation that is_alive() returns the wrong state when calling the it shortly after start() method. How can proper queuing or running state being retrieved?

```
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime


class SomeTaskMonitor(threading.Thread):
    __instance = None
    __listenerList = []

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        starts separate thread for monitoring the bus
        """
        if SomeTaskMonitor.__instance is None:
            SomeTaskMonitor.__instance = object.__new__(cls)
        return SomeTaskMonitor.__instance

    def run(self) -> None:
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            # normally list of listeners would be checked here for a match and callback initiated
            print("{0} - some event".format(datetime.now()))

    @staticmethod
    def addListener():
        if not SomeTaskMonitor().is_alive():
            SomeTaskMonitor().start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # for ease of read not adding listener here but calling class twice
    SomeTaskMonitor().addListener()

    SomeTaskMonitor().addListener()
```

Above code results in the following output (see duplicated output due to second listener registration):

```
2021-04-14 23:09:25.818950 - some event
2021-04-14 23:09:25.821855 - some event
2021-04-14 23:09:30.822109 - some event
2021-04-14 23:09:30.823741 - some event
```

Appreciate comments or recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for an answer for the above coding and the correlated question why is_alive() return value does not reflect the current state of queued or started threads.
Though, for now I'm using below WORKAROUND that suits my needs. Hope it is of help to other facing the same issue:

```
@staticmethod
def addListener():
    if len(listenerList) == 0:
        SomeTaskMonitor().start()

    listenerList.append(listener)

    #if not SomeTaskMonitor().is_alive():
    #    SomeTaskMonitor().start()
```